# psycopg2 mapping Python : "list of dicts" to Postgres : "array of composite type" for an INSERT statement

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, relational-database, psycopg2

Postgres version : 9.1.x.

Say I have the following Schema:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS posts CASCADE;
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS quotes CASCADE;

CREATE TYPE quotes AS
(
  text  CHARACTER VARYING,
  is_direct CHARACTER VARYING
);

CREATE TABLE posts
(
    body  CHARACTER VARYING,
    q     quotes[]
);
```

And I wish to perform the following insert, shown in SQL, but from Python Psycopg2.

```
insert into posts(body,q) VALUES('ninjas rock',ARRAY[ ROW('I AGREE',True)::quotes, ROW('I DISAGREE',FALSE)::quotes ]);
```

What is the syntax to achieve this (without loops and such). I am sure it is possible since the [documentation says](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#composite-types-casting) *"Changed in version 2.4.3: added support for array of composite types"*. The documentation only shows examples of `SELECT` statements.

Note: I have a list of dicts in my client code that conceptually map to the psuedo-schema above.

**edit:**

Hmm I must have missed this from the documentation : *"Adaptation from Python tuples to composite types is automatic instead and requires no adapter registration."*. Now to figure out the array part.

**edit 2:**

psycopg2's `%s` placeholder should work when the data type passed is `list(tuple)` or `list(dict)`. Gotta test it out :D

**edit3:**
Ok almost there, dicts dont work in this scenario, lists do, and tuples do. However, I need to cast the tuple string representation into the composite record type.

This :

```
quote_1 = ("monkeys rock", "False")
quote_2 = ("donkeys rock",  "True")
q_list = [ quote_1, quote_2]
print cur.mogrify("insert into posts VALUES(%s,%s)", ("animals are good", q_list))
```

Creates the following string:

```
insert into posts VALUES('animals are good',ARRAY[('monkeys rock', 'false'), ('donkeys rock', 'true')])
```

Which produces the following error :

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "q" is of type quotes[] but expression is of type record[]
```

Comment: Nice question, and thanks for following up. In future it's best if you also post your PostgreSQL version, as Pg's capabilities vary significantly from version to version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extending your efforts just a tiny bit, how about:

```python
quote_1 = ("monkeys rock", "False")
quote_2 = ("donkeys rock",  "True")
q_list = [ quote_1, quote_2]
print cur.mogrify("insert into posts VALUES(%s,%s::quotes[])", 
                  ("animals are good", q_list))
#
#                 added explicit cast to quotes[]->^^^^^^^^
```

**Explanation**:

If you run:

```sql
insert into posts 
VALUES('animals are good', ARRAY[
    ('monkeys rock', 'false'),
    ('donkeys rock', 'true')
]);
```

directly in `psql` you'll get:

```
regress=# insert into posts 
regress-# VALUES('animals are good',ARRAY[
regress-#             ('monkeys rock', 'false'),
regress-#             ('donkeys rock', 'true')
regress-#  ]);
ERROR:  column "q" is of type quotes[] but expression is of type record[]
LINE 1: insert into posts VALUES('animals are good',ARRAY[('monkeys ...
                                                    ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Sure enough, telling Pg that your anonymous array is of type `quotes[]` does the trick:

```
regress=# insert into posts 
regress-# VALUES('animals are good',ARRAY[
regress-#           ('monkeys rock', 'false'),
regress-#           ('donkeys rock', 'true')
regress-# ]::quotes[]);
INSERT 0 1

regress=# select * from posts;
       body       |                           q                            
------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
 animals are good | {"(\"monkeys rock\",false)","(\"donkeys rock\",true)"}
(1 row)
```

Comment: oh wow , you are a life saver :D I was looking through the documentation for a decoration to `%s`. I knew I would make sure such a decoration would be possible if I was working on `Psycopg` :D I'll try and send feedback to the psycopg2 guys to update the documentation.

Comment: aah `::quotes` just gets pasted verbatim into the querry. My bad =D

Comment: @HassanSyed Glad to help. You were 99% of the way there; sometimes it just takes someone else's eyes when you've been staring at the problem for hours.

Comment: All wired up an integrated :D now I can have Full text search running off a single table. Yaaay !